# Setting default user role in ArcGIS Online to custom role?

Tags: arcgis-online, authentication

I have created a custom role for ArcGIS online for all users in my organization.

Does anyone know how to set it as the default role when new users join via Enterprise login?

Right now the default role is "User".

Comment: Were you able to answer this question?